What's the meaning of "running us off an embankment"?

I married white next time and all he was good for was running us off an embankment. Marrying him was the biggest mistake of my life. He had unnatural desires. (Fat City, Leonard Gardner · 2017)

Does this phrase mean " drive us down an embankment" or is it an idiom or something like this with this meaning " getting us into trouble"?

Where does this quote come from?  Who is speaking? A longer quote might  give some context.  Could you supply a few sentences before and after?

It's not a common idiom but maybe the incident with the embankment features elsewhere in the story?

@Pete she is talking to a man about her husbands when sitting in a bar. Her first husband got shot and killed, and the second was white with unnatural desires. Just that. There isn't any extra information to help with understanding his character or the situation

@StuartF she is talking to a man about her husbands when sitting in a bar. Her first husband got shot and killed, and the second was white with unnatural desires. Just that. There isn't any extra information to help with understanding his character or the situation.

@Pete and Stuart If you check the link of the book, you will see that neither the sentence before nor the one after sheds any light. So the bigger context might be needed for help, although I doubt there is any embankment incident.

He brought us down, he caused us destruction, he drove us both to fail. And other things he wanted, I was never in the mood to back him up on. Can't recommend that one as a husband, or driver.

It is either literal or a metaphor. You need to read the rest of the book to figure out which (although both is a possibility).

Perhaps a picture would help, this one being from Wikipedia:

This hopefully clarifies the meaning. Another similar phrase might be drove us off a cliff.
In a comment, I mentioned the phrase go off the rails, alluding to a train derailing. I don't know how if people often say drive us off the rails, but I think this would be generally understood. I believe that train drivers can't actually steer the train off the rails, but they could cause a derailment if they enter a turn too fast or by hitting a stationary object.

I'm pretty sure it's much simpler than the many interesting answers given. Yes, the literal meaning has been made quite clear, but then I think there's a mistake in trying to reveal some metaphor. I've been in editing and publishing for 50 years and am a well-read native English speaker. I've never read or heard this expression used metaphorically in my life.
I'd lay odds that this was simply the narrator's way of relating in an offhand way an anecdote that the husband literally did once go off an embankment while driving with her. In any case she was clearly being ironic about such a thing possibly being "good" for her. It's probably not meant as a metaphor, but literally, in a postmodern ironical literary turn.
The use of "run" here seems unusual to some of you. Normally, if someone was "run off an embankment" it would be by, say, another vehicle. But using it in the way shown still sounds perfectly natural, colloquial, and immediately comprehensible, which is what counts. Consider, "He ran our car into a wall, and with all the kids in it."

This is a use of the verb "to run" in its sense of "to manage, to control something", here that something being a vehicle.

He ran the business into the ground.
The driver of the tour bus was drunk and ran it off the road.

Someone on the bus could say:

The driver of the tour bus was drunk and ran us off the road.

Someone driving recklessly could run other vehicles off the road:

The drunken bus driver swerved suddenly and ran a car in the adjacent lane  off the road.

The bus "guided" the other vehicle off the road, in the sense that its weight and momentum pushed the other vehicle sideways.
The prepositional phrase describes the nature of the (mis)management:

... all he was good for was running us off an embankment.

"All he was good for"  is a way of saying "he was good for almost nothing" but with a sarcastic twist -- the only thing he succeeded at was running us off an embankment.
As Xanne says in a comment, without further context there's no way to know for certain whether it should be taken literally or metaphorically, although the word "embankment" is so specific that I'm inclined to think it is to be taken literally.

Thank you so much.

Embankment means:

a raised structure (as of earth or gravel) used especially to hold back water or to carry a roadway M-W

And runoff means:

water from rain or melting snow, or liquid from an industrial or farming process, that flows into a place such as a river. (Cambridge)

And if the husband in question made the couple run off an embankment, this probably means that the situation got out of control and surpassed the limits of the acceptable (for which embankment is a metaphor). The unnatural desires seem to support this idea.
This article about Embankment preventing runoff of floodwater may shed some light on the metaphor.

I agree with your description of the likely meaning. I think the phrase didn't mean runoff, but rather run off like going off course. Another related phrase is to go off the rails, as in train tracks.

@WeiwenNg Yes, it is used as a verb (run off), but the definitions you find in the dictionaries are not relevant. The definition of the noun runoff helps you infer what the verb is about. It's water that runs off the embankment.

@fev thank you so much.

The phrase was "running us off an embankment". There is a difference between "made the couple run off" and "ran the couple off." The latter is what occurs in the quotation, not the former. @WeiwenNg was correct. The quote has nothing to do with runoff or water, even metaphorically. And the sense of embankment is the one carrying a roadway, not holding back water.
